# how to get an ordered list with default values using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `ICollection` of records `(userID,itemID,rating)` and an `IEnumerable items`

for a specific userID and each itemID from a set of itemIDs, i need to produce a list of the users rating for the items or 0 if no such record exists. the list should be ordered by the items.

example:

```
records = [(1,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,3,1)]  
items = [3,1]  
userID = 1

result = [0,2]
```

my attempt:

```
dataset.Where((x) => (x.userID == uID) & items.Contains(x.iID)).Select((x) => x.rating);
```

it does the job but it doesn't return 0 as default value and it isnt ordered...

i'm new to C# and LINQ, a pointer in the correct direction will be very appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
        var records = new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 1, 2 }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 2, 3, 1 } };
        var items = new int[] { 3, 1 };

        var userId = 1;

        var result = items.Select(i =>
        {
            // When there's a match
            if (records.Any(r => r[0] == userId && r[1] == i))
            {
                // Return all numbers
                return records.Where(r => r[0] == userId && r[1] == i).Select(r => r[2]);
            }
            else
            {
               // Just return 0
                return new int[] { 0 };
            }
        }).SelectMany(r => r); // flatten the int[][] to int[]

        // output
        result.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0} ", i));
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dataset.Where((x) => (x.userID == uID)).Select((x) => items.Contains(x.iID) ? x.rating : 0)
```

Comment: does it guarantee that the result will be sorted by the order of items ?

Comment: I don't think I get what you mean. How would you like the items ordered? There is an .OrderBy linq method.

Comment: the results are ratings, i need to know to which item each rating is associated with. in the example, the results is [0,2] because the items are [3,1]. i was thinking more in the direction of a join function...

Answer (score 0):

This does the job. But whether it's maintainable/readable solution is topic for another discussion:

```
// using your example as pseudo-code input
var records = [(1,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,3,1)];
var items = [3,1];
var userID = 1;

var output = items
    .OrderByDescending(i => i)
    .GroupJoin(records, 
               i => i, 
               r => r.ItemId, 
               (i, r) => new { ItemId = i, Records = r})
    .Select(g => g.Records.FirstOrDefault(r => r.UserId == userId))
    .Select(r => r == null ? 0 : r.Rating);
```

How this query works...

- ordering is obvious
- the ugly `GroupJoin` - it joins every element from `items` with all records that share same `ItemId` into annonymous type `{ItemId, Records}`
- now we select first record for each entry that matches `userId` - if none is found, `null` will be returned (thanks to `FirstOrDefault`)
- last thing we do is check whether we have value (we select `Rating`) or not - `0`

Answer (score 0):

How about this. your question sounds  bit like an outer join from SQL, and you can do this with  a GroupJoin, SelectMany:

```
var record1 = new Record() { userID = 1, itemID = 1, rating = 2 };
var record2 = new Record() { userID = 1, itemID = 2, rating = 3 };
var record3 = new Record() { userID = 2, itemID = 3, rating = 1 };

var records = new List<Record>  { record1, record2, record3 };

int userID = 1;
var items = new List<int> { 3, 1 };

var results = items
.GroupJoin( records.Where(r => r.userID == userID), item => item, record => record.itemID, (item, record) => new { item, ratings = record.Select(r => r.rating) } )
.OrderBy( itemRating => itemRating.item)
.SelectMany( itemRating => itemRating.ratings.DefaultIfEmpty(), (itemRating, rating) => rating);
```

To explain what is going on

- For each item GroupJoin gets the list of rating (or empty list if no rating) for the specified user
- OrderBy is obvious
- SelectMany flattens the ratings lists, providing a zero if the ratings list is empty (by DefaultIfEmpty)

Hope this makes sense.

Be aware, if there is more than one rating for an item by a user, they will all appear in the final list.